# Two group elements induce the same permutation on $A$ if and only if they are in the same coset of the kernel.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> Page 113 - Dummit and Foote - Group actions
>
> Two group elements induce the same permutation on $A$ if and only if they are in the same coset of the kernel.

What does this mean? Two permutations induce the same permutation on $A$ looks like it means $\sigma_1 A = A' = \sigma_2 A$ and then I don't really understand the right hand side of the $\iff$.

Comment: Could you provide more context? What group action are you dealing with and which kernel is meant here?

Comment: @StefanHamcke I don't know what is relevant context unfortunately, it just came up in D&F and I had read all the previous parts of the chapter, that seem unrelated

Answer (score 2):

This is my understanding of the text:

Let group $G$ act on $A$ as $g.a$ $\forall g \in G$ and $a\in A$

Let $\phi: G \to S_A$ be the associated permutation representation (homomorphism)

Let $K$ be the kernel of this map, which is also the kernel of the group action.

Then according to me, the text says

$\phi(g)= \phi(h) \iff gK = hK$

$$\phi(g)=\phi(h)$$

$$ \iff \phi(g)(a)=\phi(h)(a)\; \forall a\in A$$

$$\iff g.a=h.a \; \;\forall a \in A$$

$$\iff h^{-1}.(g.a)= (h^{-1}).(h.a) \; \; \forall a \in A$$

$$\iff (h^{-1}g).a=(h^{-1}h).a=1.a=a  \; \;\forall a \in A$$

$$\iff h^{-1}g \in K$$

$$\iff gK = hK$$

Answer (score -1):

An action $G\stackrel{}{\curvearrowright} A$ is equivalent to a homomorphism $\varphi \colon G\to\operatorname{Sym}(A)$,  via $\varphi_g(a):=:g\cdot a$. Therefore:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\varphi_g=\varphi_h\iff \\
&\varphi_g\varphi_h^{-1}=Id_A\iff \\
&\varphi_g\varphi_{h^{-1}}=Id_A\iff \\
&\varphi_{gh^{-1}}=Id_A\iff \\
&gh^{-1}\in\ker\varphi\iff \\
&g\in(\ker\varphi)h \\
\end{alignat}
And of course $h\in(\ker\varphi)h$.